# PHP: Initiate Variable With Multiple Lines

Tags: php, variables, buffer

I know I can make a new variable by simply saying `$var = "stuff"`, but how would I make one like this:

```
<?php
$var = ?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<? ; ?>
```

Do you see what I am getting at? Is there a way to create a variable without having to be restrictive and using `= "";`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/string

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [Heredoc](http://php.net/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
$var = <<<HTML
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
HTML;
```

Note, that the end token (here `HTML;`) *must* be on a line for itself without any leading or trailing whitespaces (except the newline at the end).

Additional you can just put everything into a string like usual, but with newlines

```
$var = '<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>';
```

Or add newline characters yourself

```
$var = '<html>' . PHP_EOL;
$var .= '<head>' . PHP_EOL;
$var .= '</head>' . PHP_EOL;
$var .= '<body>' . PHP_EOL;
$var .= '</body>' . PHP_EOL;
$var .= '</html>';
```

or

```
$var = "<html>\n<head>\n</head>\n<body>\n</body>\n</html>";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse PHP variables (like you would with a double quote), use the [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax.

If you want no parsing of variables, use the [NOWDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) syntax.

Comment: After reading the documentation, I am confused. How would I run PHP within HEREDOC vs. NOWDOC?

Comment: Just like how `$a = 'one'; $parsed = "$a";` $parsed will be `one`, if you use PHP variables in a HEREDOC, the value of the variable is inserted. In a NOWDOC, the value is exactly what you type. (No parsing).

Comment: So you don't run PHP in a HEREDOC, but variables are recognized and the values inserted in place.

Answer (score -1):

something like [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)?

Comment: [Please don't answer with just a link.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)  Explain why your link answers the question and add in quotes or examples from the linked resource to provide context.