# PHP not adding to an array as expected

Tags: php, html, forms

So, here's an overview of what I'm trying to do, I am keeping track of a list of students that attended an event. The list will get stored in a variable along with some other information about the event, and the information will get sent as an email.

I am trying to make it so that the user simply has to enter student names as [first name] [last name], one on each line. The program will then take the entire textarea list as one string, and split it by new line characters. From this newly created list, it will split each item by space characters, and rearrange the list as [lastname] [comma] [firstname], and then sort it into ascending alphabetical order for convenience.

I have a form in my HTML code:
`<form action="submitted.php" method="post">`

The submitted information will go to my script "submitted.php" and use the `POST` method.

Inside the form I have a `textarea`: `<textarea id="studentList" name="stuList"></textarea>`

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    /* get some other variables first */
    $msg = ""; // holds the entire email message body

    /* get the values from the textarea */
    $list = $_POST["stuList"]; // use the 'name' attribute on the textarea

    // split the student list
        $list = explode("\n", $list);
        $newList = array();

        for($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++) {
            $arr = explode(" ", $list[$i]);

            $fName = $arr[0];
            $lName = $arr[1];

            $newList[] = $lName . ", " . $fName;
        }


        sort($newList);

        for($i = 0; $i < count($newList); $i++) {
            $msg .= ($newList[$i] . "\n");
        }

        mail($toAddr, $subject, $msg, $fromAddr);
?>
```

The problem is that in the email message, there are more "new lines" than there should be. For instance, if I enter some values into the text field:

```
John Smith
Andy Jones
Sally Sue
```

The list is sorted by last name correctly, but it appears like this:

```
Jones, Andy
Smith
, John
Sue
, Sally
```

Any help appreciated, let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: By the way, instead of looping through $newList to create $message, you can just use implode($message, "\n")

Comment: No, I'm on Mac, but I can try implode and see how it works.

Comment: Update: implode is convenient, so thanks for that, but it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: Try echo-ing the string to determine if the issue is in the string building or in the email!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934025/php-initiate-variable-with-multiple-lines

Comment: The issue was a mail issue. It was not correctly interpreting "\n" as a new line, so it got messed up somewhere. I converted it to an HTML email and it works fine now. Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to replicate the output OP reported but wanted to help simplify the code a little bit while still getting the desired result.

I'm using an associative array to make the code simpler and to remove the necessity to have "lastName, firstName". Of course you can change the code to still use that format.

```
$list = $_POST["stuList"];
$list = explode("\n", $list);
$newList = array();

foreach ($list as $item) {
    $nameParts = explode(" ", $item);
    $newList[$nameParts[1]] = $item;
}

ksort($newList);

$msg = implode(",\n", $newList)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to fix the issue by changing it to an HTML email instead of just using plain text.